# What does those SDKs doing? (win 10 UWP visual studio)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sdk, uwp

Since I had a problem with my Visual Studio I have to reinstall it, I start programming at UWP, so i need the Tools 1.4.1, but when I open it on Visual Studio, there is the "Tools 1.4.1  and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393)" and down there another 2 SDKs (10.0.10586 and 10240) and the wieght a lot, I'm trying to remove stuff, but are they "must" to download to program with UWP?

Comment: The different SDKs expose the functionality of the respective versions of Windows (e.g. 10.0.14393 for the Windows 10 Anniversary Update). Targeting a specific version of Windows through the SDK prevents you from accidentally using a type or member, that has been introduced in a later version. You can use the latest SDK to build software for previous versions of Windows, but you will have to make sure the features you use are available on your target platform.

Comment: @IInspectable, this should be an answer, not a comment :)